# Comparator.naturalOrder() giving compiler error when implementing in class

Tags: java, generics, comparator

When trying to implement the no-arg constructor for this class the compiler is giving me the following error:
Type mismatch: cannot convert from Comparator<Comparable<? super Comparable<? super T>>> to Comparator<? super E>

I'm trying to implement the following class:

```
class HeapWithComparator<E>{
    private Comparator<? super E> comparator; // For comparing elements
    
    private ArrayList<E> a = new ArrayList<>();
    
    public HeapWithComparator() {
    // No arg constructor implementing a comparator for natural order
        **this.comparator = Comparator.naturalOrder()**;
    }
    public HeapWithComparator(Comparator<? super E> comparator) {
        this.comparator = comparator;
    
    }
    
    public int getSize() {
        return a.size();
    }
    
    
}
```

I understand that this has to do with E having to implement comparable. Would casting the comparator into Type mismatch: cannot convert from Comparator<Comparable<? super Comparable<? super T>>> to Comparator<? super E> work?

Comment: Please format your code.

Comment: I don't see how the code you provide gets the error you mention, as you don't declare any type parameter `E`.

Comment: You just need to give E bounds: `HeapWithComparator<E extends Comparable<E>>`, otherwise `naturalOrder()` can't give you a `Comparator`, as it relies on `E` being `Comparable`. Its signatuire is `public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> Comparator<T> naturalOrder()`

Comment: You just need `Comparator.<E>naturalOrder()`, as long as `E extends Comparable`, which the compiler will test for you here. If it doesn't, the comparator wouldn't work anyway.

Comment: I really don't know if anything other than casting can work here: (Comparator<? super E>) Comparator.naturalOrder()

Comment: @Beri When you try it my way you will know more.

Comment: @user207421 You're missing the point of this code. The class needs a way to compare elements, so it requires *either* a comparator *or* comparable elements, similar to TreeMap and PriorityQueue and List.sort(). Constraining E at the class level is not an option.

Comment: @shmosel It has to be an option. Otherwise you can't use `naturalOrder()` at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use casting to circumvent the type mismatch:

```
this.comparator = (Comparator<? super E>)Comparator.naturalOrder();
```

But there's always a risk it'll be used for a non-Comparable type. A better solution is to instead expose a static factory constrained to ensure `E` is Comparable:

```
public static <C extends Comparable<? super C>> HeapWithComparator<C> naturallyOrdered() {
    return new HeapWithComparator<>(Comparator.naturalOrder());
}
```

Comment: `Comparator.<E>naturalOrder()` is a lot simpler than either.

Comment: But it doesn't compile.